# python my selenium "webdriver.Remote" not work? .It's a real headache

Tags: python

Why does my "webdriver.Remote" not work?

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    options=options
)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

[image]

I tried running "webdriver.Chrome" locally directly and it was successful

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
# options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should consider adding the error message in the body of your message, preferably within quote tags. This will drive more views to your message and avoid broken links.

Answer (score 0):

I found that he kept Starting "Starting ChromeDriver 100.0.4896.60" while running, so I found another "ChromeDriver "in the selenium-server.jar sibling directory.How stupid of me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).